# Powershell select unique field

Tags: powershell, unique, select-object

I've got a list of object with some fields. For example, there are three object of my list:

```
Field1 = "aaa"
Field2 = 123
Field3 = "ccc"

Field1 = "bbb"
Field2 = 123
Field3 = "ddd"

Field1 = "eee"
Field2 = 123
Field3 = "ccc"
```

I need to filter this list like this:

- I must take all unique occurrences of pair Field2-Field3. Value of Field1 is unnecessary.

In my example, the result of selecting must delete the third object because has same value on Field2 and Field3.

I've tried with `Select-Object -Unique Field2, Field3` but doesn't filter anything.

I've also tried with `Where-Object` with same negative result.

Any idea? I'm using older version of powershell so i can't use some of cmdlets.

Thank you.

here's the code: it works, but i need to get also Field1 in my output

```
$result = @{}
 foreach($item in $myList) {
       $combined = '{0}-{1}' -f $item.Field2, $item.Field3
       if($result.ContainsKey($combined) -eq $false) {
          $result[$combined] = $item
       }
    }
    $result.Values
```

Comment: *I've tried with `Select-Object -Unique Field2, Field3` but doesn't filter anything.* Can you show [mcve] demonstrating this? [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30GDSwEIogOCnUuLS/Jz/ZOyUpNLYhUcqsHiIOCWmZqTYqhgq6CUmJiohCpsBBQ2NDJGFTQGqU1OToaorSXBgqSkJKItSElJId2C1NRUcnygqVCjEJyaAzRXF2K8gm5oXmZhaSrUDB2otv//AQ)

Comment: I don't see `$result = @{}` in that code that you posted.

Comment: you're right. now it works, but my output is:
Name: Field2-Field3 Value: all-my-object-field-and-values

how can select only field that i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression:

```
$objects | Select -Unique @{n='Combined'; e={'{0}-{1}' -f $_.Field2, $_.Field3}}
```

Here is another way using a hash:

```
$result = @{}
foreach($item in $objects){
    $combined = '{0}-{1}' -f $item.Field2, $item.Field3
    if($result.ContainsKey($combined) -eq $false){
        $result[$combined] = $item
    }
}
$result.Values | Select Field1
```

Comment: i can't understand your expression and seems doesn't works on my code. I need also to select Field1 from my object list

Comment: ContainsKey method doesn't exist. i received an error on this line.

Comment: Not sure what you have going on then. ContainsKey is most certainly a valid method on a hash. Please update your question with the actual code you are running.

Comment: @maures Edited to only get Field1 values